# Handling symlinks in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

The Matlab functions exist() and dir() seem to ignore symlinks. Can you tell me how to find out if a symlink exists?

```
>> exist('./path/to/symlink', 'file') 

ans =

     0

>> size(dir('./path/to/symlink'),1) 

ans =

     0
```

Edit: The problem is actually worse than just checking for existence. The usual functions can't even follow a symlink to open the file. Trying to use `dlmread()`, for example returns a "no such file or directory" error.

Edit: Now I cannot reproduce the problem. It must have been some sort of user error.

Comment: What O/S are you using? Mac aliases are different to Unix symlinks as explained here: http://superuser.com/questions/253984/mac-terminal-cd-to-a-folder-alias

Comment: This was on MacOS 10.7.

Comment: I stumbled to the question due to same problem, my OS is Solaris. Apparently any path in a symlink (for matlab to follow) should have the whole path (absolute) anything relative would not work in solaris / matlab.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you sure? They work just fine on my install (ubuntu+R2012a).

Note that in linux, pathnames are case sensitive which is not the case on windows!

You should test if the link isn't broken by `ls`-ing it in a terminal:

```
ls -l
```

and see if the file the link points at also exists.

Answer (score 0):

In MATLAB you can use

```
~isempty(dir(symLinkPath))  % Returns 0 if the symlink itself does not exist
```

to check existence of a symlink itself (not the target that it links to). To check the existence of the target of the symlink, you can use

```
exist(symLinkPath)  % Returns 0 if target of symlink does not exist
```